# Finite abelian groups and a group number morphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Considering $\alpha(k)$ to be the number of finite abelian groups of order $k$, how can one prove that
if $n,m \in N$ with $gcd(n,m) = 1$, then $\alpha(n) \cdot \alpha(m) = \alpha(n \cdot m)?$

---

Looks like here $\alpha(k)$ represents all the ways one can decompose a number $k$ into some powers of some primes. So one can probably use the fundamental theorem of arithmetics but I just can't find a formal proof.

Comment: You need [the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the structure theorem, which states that a finite abelian group can be written as $\prod_{p,r_p,j} Z_{p^{j}}^{r_{p^j}}$, where $r_p$ depends only on the group, and the set ${r_p}$ uniquely defines the group. Your statement is equivalent to proving that $\alpha(p^rq^k) = \alpha(p^r)\alpha(q^k)$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes.
Now it is just a combinatorial problem: $\alpha(q^r)=p(r)$, where $p(r)$ is the number of partition of $r$, and this is multiplicative.